# Setting programmatically the layout background color = nullpointerexc

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm using shared preferences in my app to set different background colors.

```
private void loadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    boolean isBackgroundDark = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("background_color",false);
    if(isBackgroundDark){
        LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainActivityLayout);
        mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3c3f41"));

    }
    String notebookTitle = sharedPreferences.getString("title","Notebook");
    setTitle(notebookTitle);
}
```

This code works fine, the color of mainlayout changes.
But when I want change the color of simply row item

private void loadPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

```
    boolean isBackgroundDark = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("background_color",false);
    if(isBackgroundDark){
        LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainActivityLayout);
        mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3c3f41"));
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.list_row_rel_layout);
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3c3f41"));
    }
    String notebookTitle = sharedPreferences.getString("title","Notebook");
    setTitle(notebookTitle);
}
```

In the xml file of this relative layout the id is define

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#FFF9F9F9"
      android:id="@+id/list_row_rel_layout"
      android:paddingRight="10dp"
      android:paddingTop="10dp"
      android:paddingBottom="10dp"...
/>
```

Logs below:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.bczyzowski.notebook, PID: 20754
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bczyzowski.notebook/com.bczyzowski.notebook.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at com.bczyzowski.notebook.MainActivity.loadPreferences(MainActivity.java:77)
                                                                         at com.bczyzowski.notebook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Can you show your logs?

Comment: @AhmedHegazy logs added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to find a view that is not under your current layout view structure. The RelativeLayout is the problem here it can't be found under the view you set in `setContentView();`.

Comment: And how can I access this relative layout in other way ?

Comment: What do you use it for?

Comment: Is a list row used in a class which extends the array adapter.

Comment: You can't use it outside your adapter. You should use it after inflating the layout in your adapter. And get it by calling view.findViewById(); the view is the object you got when inflating the layout using any of the inflating alternatoves.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help and explain ;)

Comment: Please mark is as the correct answer if it answers yourr question :)

Answer (score 0):

Set it as global variable in your activity before `onCreate`

```
private LinearLayout mainLayout;
```

and then in `onCreate` of your activity

```
mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainActivityLayout);
```

and then in your method

```
private void loadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    boolean isBackgroundDark = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("background_color",false);
        if(isBackgroundDark){
                    mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3c3f41"));
            }
            String notebookTitle = sharedPreferences.getString("title","Notebook");
            setTitle(notebookTitle);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: As I said before the setBackgroundColor for linear layout works fine, the relative layout is causing a problem...

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question that you are using this **RelativeLayout** for an **item** of **custom listview**. And the **View** of your **MainActivity** is **mainActivityLayout**.

If my guess is true, you can't access this **RelativeLayout** from inside the **MainActivity** because the **RelativeLayout** not part of the **mainActivityLayout**,

but you can access it from inside the **getView()** function of the **Adapter** of your custom listview.

hope it helps